# TinyMCE 'Ctrl + A' shortcut is not working in Firefox?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE editor the select all (Ctrl+A) option is working Edge & Chrome.

But in Mozilla Firefox that option not working.

```
 setup: function(editor)   {
     editor.shortcuts.add('Ctrl+a', "SelectAll", function()                    {
    
         });
     },
```

The above code I need add some logic in this case Ctrl+A not working in Firefox.

Code: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/sAiaab/2

please help me

Why the select all (Ctrl+A) option is not working Firefox? and How to fix the Problem?

Thanks